# How can i reCalculate route on waypoint change?

Tags: here-api

I'm using JS api. I need to recalculate route if waypoint is changed (via input field or waypoint marker is dragged).
As i understand, we can't recalculate existing route, so we need to destroy the previous one and to make the new one?
So how should i destroy the existing one as i have only "routes" object available inside the addWaypointsToMap function?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i resolved it.
The moment route is changed (waypoint dragged or relocated) i check if map groups for polygon and waypoints markers exist and kill'em, then make new route.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what does exactly "recalculate existing route" means, but if it means to update Polyline map object based on new routing response then you can simply use

`H.map.Polyline#setGeometry()`

The method is documented here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.16.1/api_reference/H.map.Polyline.html#setGeometry

Here is a simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsdrwLe3/1/) example to set start & destination (as well as middle waypoint) point by mouse right-click and re-calculate the route.